# Configuring Domino Server to use Web Service behind the dmz

Tags: web-services, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

our supplier programs for us a webservice which is reachable over the www. Now I like to consum this webservice in a Lotus Notes Database. I import the wsdl file in the Domino Design an developed two buttons in a form to consum the webservice. The first button start the WebService over the Notes Client, the second button start the WebService over the Domino Server.

Now my problems start, when I consume the Web Service over the Client i get an error:

Web-Service AddPortType, Methode add - Fehler Fehler beim Verbindungsaufbau zu 'xxxproxy.xxx.xxx' auf Port '3128', SSL Fehlerhaftes Peer-Zertifikat. Verbindung wurde abgelehnt.

When I consume the Web Service over the Server, the Server get an error:

14.03.2016 12:38:53   Agent 'add' error: Web Service AddPortType method add error Error connecting to 'xxx.xx-xxx.de' on port '443', The server is not responding. The server may be down or you may be experiencing network problems. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists.

First of all I decide to solve the Problem on the Server, because I think it's easyer to solve one Problem on one server as to solve one problem one many many clients.

The webservice must be reachable because, I can open it in the browser, an when I consum it over the Client, it looks like the connection isn't the problem.

In our network we have an proxyserver between the Domino Server and the Webservice.

So may the connection between domino server and Proxy is the Problem. I try the configur this proxy server in the server document in the names.nsf.

Proxy-Konfiguration

HTTP-Proxy:http://xxx.xx.xx:3128

FTP-Proxy:http://

Gopher-Proxy:http://

SSL-Sicherheits-Proxy:http://

HTTP-Tunnel-Proxy:http://

SOCKS-Proxy:Kein Proxy für folgende Hosts und Domänen:

But this change anything, the error message is still the same.

Did anyone can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As SSL is involved, I had some issues running Java Agents getting content from https sites because of too strong certificates and disabled SSL. 
Public sites nowadays use SHA-2 and TLS. But the java core on Domino do not seem to fully support this.